# How to include multiple -notmatch items in powershell Get-Content

Tags: powershell

```
$removeLines = (Get-Content $path) -notmatch '$acct' -and '06`^' | Set-Content $saveAs
```

I have a file that looks like this.

```
01^333333333333
03^333333333333
06^333333333333
01^555555555555
02^555555555555
02^555555555555
02^555555555555
03^555555555555
06^555555555555
```

I'm trying to get the content of the file and output it like this: (without the line beinning with 06^ where 555555555555 follows

```
01^333333333333
03^333333333333
06^333333333333
01^555555555555
02^555555555555
02^555555555555
02^555555555555
03^555555555555
```

So this line should be removed `06^555555555555`
How can I add multiple -notmatch items so that only the one line is removed? I have messed with the syntax for like 30 minutes and can't figure it out, surely it's simple.

Bonus points, can I do a notmatch with a regex? something like (...555555555555)+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is regex.  So you have to escape (using a backslash) the '^'.

```
get-content $path | where { -not ($_ -match $acct -and $_ -match '06\^') }
```

or

```
get-content $path | where { $_ -notmatch $acct -or $_ -notmatch '06\^' }
```

or

```
(Get-Content $path) -notmatch "^06\^$acct"
```

Comment: `(Get-Content $path) -notmatch "^06\^$acct"` This is what I needed thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for looks something like this: `$removeLines = (Get-Content $path) -notmatch "$acct\^\d+" | Set-Content $saveAs`

You can't chain -ands. You need to do something like `$x -notmatch 'a' -and $x -notmatch 'b'`